# Is it possible to draw overlay over any screen using 3rd party app in android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, smart-tv

I have a question related to android TV. We want to create an app for android TVs which can run as service and is able to put overlay on any live tv or any screen and is able to show some text/video. Is this possible to do on android tv with a 3rd party app.

It may be a very basic question but sorry for my ignorance. Would appreciate if someone can answer me. If I know the answer, then I will try to research more to create the app. Over internet, I could not find any answer to my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. You just need to start a transparent activity from the Service.

This will allow you to show content on the screen regardless of the input source, but ONLY if it is a physical TV with Android TV, since when you have an Android TV box connected to the TV, it is already limited to that particular input source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will other apps allow to overlay something on top of them, specially live tv? Also, cannot i just use an android box for development and a monitor? If I connect an android box to android tv, then it is one of the input sources.

Comment: you are not drawing over other apps (that is a very dangerous permission), you are having an activity with a transparent background, it is different.
If you use an Android TV box, you can only overlay on the content display by the box (i.e. that same source) while on an Android TV it works for all sources.

Comment: Indeed I want to draw over other apps. I am fine asking user for the permission like "draw over other apps". I know we can do this on android mobile but am not sure if this is possible for TV. It should be fine if I can draw over particular input source (tv box in my case) as I am doing this for demo purpose only.

Comment: as I said, you can achieve what you want with an Activity with a transparent theme, no need to ask for the permission to draw over other apps.